# Problems with installing packages

Tags: r, install.packages

I have a problem with installing a package, because I get an error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in “install.packages(“install_github(…
```

I’m using a MacBook Air and my friends who are using Microsoft don’t have this problem.

Comment: remove `install.packages`, you cannot combine `install.packages` and `install_github`, directly use `install_github(...)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

First, your code uses curly quotes: `“`, when you need to use straight quotes: `"`. This usually occurs because some programs autoreplace straight quotes, but that shouldn’t happen in RStudio or in the R GUI. Where are you writing your code?

Second, `install_github()` is a command included in the remotes or devtools package. So you would start by installing one of those packages.

```
install.packages("remotes")
```

Finally, after installing, you would load remotes, and then use `install_github()` directly.

```
library(remotes)

install_github("user/package")
```